Have created HTML form - struggling to get it to send email to my client with the user input data from the form
I have been learning HTML, CSS and Javascript so far and have built an enquiries form on a website that I am building.
In order for my client to be able to easily gather the data that form users submit, I would like to get the form to send an email to her email address, with the information that the user has inputted, when they click the submit button.
I understand that I may need to use PHP to do this but I haven't learnt any PHP yet, as I've not yet started back-end languages - I have been learning front-end so far.
I have included my HTML code below.  I can provide the CSS code if needed.  I would like some guidance as to: -

Whether it's worth trying to work out how to do this through PHP yet, or whether it's worth shelving the form functionality until further down the line when I have started learning back-end languages.
Whether there is an alternative simple way of enabling my client to gather the user data, bearing in mind that she does not have coding skills, that does not involve use of back-end languages (does not have to involve emailing her the form data, as long as it is simple for her to use).
Some guidance on how I would go about sorting this through PHP.  I have seen snippets of PHP code that are relevant to this issue, but I am struggling to understand them.

            <form id="enquiriesForm" class="flex-item">
                <label for="firstName" class="flex-item"><h5><b>First Name</b></h5></label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="flex-item" required>
                <br />
                <label for="secondName" class="flex-item"><h5><b>Second Name</b></h5></label>
                    <input type="text" id="secondName" name="secondName" class="flex-item"                    required>
                <br />
                <label for="emailAddress" class="flex-item"><h5><b>Email Address</b></h5></label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" class="flex-item" required>
                <br />
                <label for="phoneNumber" class="flex-item"><h5><b>Phone Number <h6><b>(optional field)</b></h6></b></h5></label>
                    <input type="number" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" class="flex-item">
                <br />
                <h5 class="flex-item"><b>Please choose the services that you are interested in</b></h5> <h6><b>(you can select more than one option)</b></h6>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option" value="blockOfFourClasses" class="flex-item">
                        <label for="option1" class="flex-item"><b>Block of Four Classes at Venue</b></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="option" value="privateTuitionOwnHome" class="flex-item">
                        <label for="option2" class="flex-item"><b>Private Tuition in my Own Home</b></label>    
                    <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="option" value="privateTuitionStudio" class="flex-item">
                        <label for="option3" class="flex-item"><b>Private Tuition in Mirrored Studio</b></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="option4" name="option" value="antenatalConsultation" class="flex-item">
                        <label for="option4" class="flex-item"><b>Antenatal Consultation</b></label>
                <br />
                <h5 class="flex-item"><b>Do you want to be added to our mailing list?</b></h5>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="yesNo" value="yes" class="flex-item">
                        <label for="radio1" class="flex-item"><b>Yes</b></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="yesNo" value="no" class="flex-item">
                        <label for="radio2" class="flex-item"><b>No</b></label>
                <br />
                <label for="freeTextComments" class="flex-item"><h5><b>Please Type Your Enquiry Here</b></h5></label>
                    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" cols="30" class="flex-item"></textarea>
                <br />
                <br />   
                <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="flex-item"><span><h4><strong>Submit</strong></h4></span></button> 
</form>

I was ideally trying to avoid using a Javascript function to process the user input, unless I can get the Javascript function to email the users' input to my client (which I understand that I can't).  This is because I presumed that a Javascript function would be too complicated for someone who does not how to code to access the user data.
If I am wrong on this and there is a relatively simple way of sorting this, and her accessing the user data, through Javascript, I would appreciate some guidance on this.

There are several point-and-click form systems e.g. one from Google that can be embedded into websites. Sometimes they are enough. Would that work for your use case?

Google Forms. Microsoft Forms. Other vendors with similar products. Then you can export the data from their backends in various ways, including just downloading a spreadsheet. Getting each entry in a separate email is fine if each piece of data stands completely alone, but it's no good if you want to do any analysis on all the data which is submitted, or even show it in a list easily, or process it in some way. Or if you prefer to stick with the idea of having your own backend, consider storing the data in a database, instead of (or as well as) sending it via email.

There are many many examples of email contact forms online though, showing you the PHP code you'd need. You don't necessarily need to write your own, or even understand the code examples in much detail. Or if you use a CMS, e.g. Wordpress or similar, for your website, they generally come with modules which let you build this kind of thing into your site with low or no coding of your own required. I applaud your desire to learn to code, but in terms of simply getting this feature online, you really don't need to re-invent the wheel.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Many thanks for all the advice. I have thought about embedding Google Forms or Microsoft Forms, but I didn't know if there would be a cost implication for that that would end up costing my client money.  Are any of these options free?

As I'm doing this website in order to improve my coding knowledge, and build my portfolio, I have been keen to build the logic behind my form using coding, but I appreciate that it may not be the best way.
